# Optimizar codigo VBA

Tags: vba, optimización

soy nuevo programando y tengo un código donde muestro u UserForm con cierta información pero al momento de ejecutar dicho código se demora mucho en salir e UserForm, ¿como puedo mejorar el codigo?, la idea de este codigo es una busqueda inteligente sobre una tabla que esta escrita una hoja excel:

```
Private Sub TEXTO_Change()
NumeroDatos = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
x = 4
ComboBox1_Change
''MsgBox NumeroDatos
Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
Me.LISTA = Clear
Me.LISTA.RowSource = Clear
y = 0

For FILA = 2 To NumeroDatos
descrip = Sheet1.Cells(FILA, 2).Value
descri = Sheet1.Cells(FILA, 1).Value

    If (UCase(descrip) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TEXTO.Value) & "*" Or UCase(descri) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TEXTO.Value) & "*") Then

    Me.LISTA.AddItem
    Me.LISTA.List(y, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(FILA, 1).Value
    Me.LISTA.List(y, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(FILA, 2).Value
    Me.LISTA.List(y, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(FILA, 3).Value
    Me.LISTA.List(y, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(FILA, x).Value

    y = y + 1

    End If


Next

End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.AddItem "2019"
ComboBox1.AddItem "2020"
ComboBox1.AddItem "2021"
ComboBox1.AddItem "2022"
Me.LISTA.RowSource = "PRODUCTOS"
Me.LISTA.ColumnCount = 4

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué hay en la macro `ComboBox1_Change`? Porque la llamas desde tu código...

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad sería pausar la actualización de la pantalla. Por ejemplo, antes del for: 
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Luego del bucle, volvés a activarlo:
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Para más info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating